# Pandas rank but return with a str?

Tags: python, pandas, rank

A Simple Example

```
Index  Name    Gender    City       Points(need to be Rank) 

 0     Ada       F       NewYork      100
 1     Lily      F       London       50
 2     Peter     M       HongKong     90
 3     Joe       M       Tokyo        70 
 4     Mark      M       London       30
```

The problem is: if use Name/City.groupby & .agg(rank) to get the ranking of Points, the Gender str will lost!

```
Index  Name     City        Rank(Points column after rank)

 0     Ada        NewYork       1
 1     Lily       London        1
 2     Peter      Honkong       1
 3     Joe        Tokyo         1 
 4     Mark       London        2(Rank in London)
```

If  merge the second DF back to first DF is not allowed,
How would you Rank points and still got the str of Gender column？

Comment: Why dont use rank along?

Comment: `df["rank"] = df["Points"].rank(method="dense", ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1):

##### updated answer

use `groupby.rank` and assign it to your new column

```
df.assign(Rank=df.groupby('City')['Points'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense'))
# or for in place modification
# df['Rank'] = df.groupby('City')['Points'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense')
```

output:

```
   Index   Name Gender      City  Points  Rank
0      0    Ada      F   NewYork     100   1.0
1      1   Lily      F    London      50   1.0
2      2  Peter      M  HongKong      90   1.0
3      3    Joe      M     Tokyo      70   1.0
4      4   Mark      M    London      30   2.0
```

##### older answer

Directly use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html), no groupby is needed:

```
df.assign(Rank=df['Points'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense'))
```

output:

```
   Index   Name      City  Points  Rank
0      0    Ada   NewYork     100   1.0
1      1   Lily    London      50   4.0
2      2  Peter  HongKong      90   2.0
3      3    Joe     Tokyo      70   3.0
```

Comment: I am very thanks and sorry to you my borther Mozway. It was a suck example i have changed it. There are at least TWO str i need to group them and rank, but i dont know how to return the rank value with specific str.